# How to override app_settings while testing

Tags: django, testing, django-settings

Okay now, I have

#### settings.py

```
SETTING1='value'
SETTING2='value'
```

After that we realized that these settings `SETTING1` and `SETTING2` are more specified to `app1`
So we've added them `apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class EXAPPConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'EXAPPConfig'
    verbose_name = "EXAPPConfig"
    SETTING1 = 'value'
    def ready(self):
        pass
```

and call them with`views.py`

```
app_settings = apps.get_app_config('ex_app')
app_settings.SETTING1
```

according to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/)

So how can I override them with override_settings at tests
`@override_settings`
I tried @patch to patch the config app but failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock only an attribute of your app config with this:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

from django.apps import apps
from django.test import TestCase


class EXAPPTest(TestCase):
    def test_mocking_app_config(self):
        original = apps.get_app_config('ex_app').SETTING1
        with patch.object(apps.get_app_config('ex_app'), 'SETTING1', new='definitely-not-original'):
            mocked = apps.get_app_config('ex_app').SETTING1
        self.assertNotEqual(original, mocked)
```

Comment: yeah I tried to patch the whole class for AppConfig not the attribute only